# How to disable click on overlay bubble for accessibility service?

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibilityservice

I am implementing the auto click feature for my project. I hope that the accessibility service, when it starts running, will not be able to interact with the overlay bubble. However, the result is that it can still interact with buttons in the overlay bubble.

Here is my code

onCreate Bubble Service

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val pm = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "layout_bubble:service")

        mBubbleView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_bubble, null)

        mBubbleParams = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
        } else {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            )
        }

        mBubbleParams?.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or Gravity.START

        mWindowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        mWindowManager?.addView(mBubbleView, mBubbleParams)

    }
```

AutoClick Service

```
    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        autoClickService = this
        startService(Intent(this, AutoClickService::class.java)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
    }

    fun click(x: Float, y: Float) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) return
        val path = Path()
        path.moveTo(x, y)
        val builder = GestureDescription.Builder()
        val gestureDescription = builder
            .addStroke(GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0L, 10L))
            .build()
        this.dispatchGesture(gestureDescription, null, null)
    }
```

start Auto Click

```
     if (autoClickService != null) {
       autoClickService?.click(x,y)
       Thread.sleep(40L)
   }
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the window type of the overlay bubble to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY

```
    val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)
```

Comment: When I use WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY for versions higher than Android O, the app will encounter a crash.

Comment: The TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY constant is a safer alternative to TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY you can replace it